# Static vs non static Activity intent calling method

Tags: java, android, android-intent, static, static-methods

Here I am a little bit confuse about Static Intent calling method vs Direct intent calling. What is better choice for creating New Activity as memory point of view?

As per I know if intent method calling with static it contains memory for application lives. is it true or not?

Let move to take example :

In Activity B

```
public static Intent newIntent(Context context) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(context, B.class);
       return intent;
   }
```

Calling Activity B from Activity A

In Activity A

```
 startActivity(B.newIntent(this));
```

or

In other way direct calling activity can not live after finish() Calling activity. right?

```
startActivity(new Intent(context, B.class));
```

Still I guess second is better then as code point of you and memory point of view. But I see many projects contains first(static calling) method. So I want to know what is better selection to calling new Activity?

Comment: Will in my humble opinion, the first one is good if your activity B has to be started with some specific extras or intent flags, which activity A not needs to know about. If the activity intent is just a normal intent, I think it is just amatter of taste.

Comment: My question is about will it contains extra memory then normal calling?

Comment: I think create common Intent call in BaseActivity would be great. We can also manage STACK clear , finish etc.

Answer (score 1):

The method `public static Intent newIntent()` is static, but that's all that is static. The use of this static method is that you can call `B.newIntent()` without having an instance of `B`.

The context you pass to `B.newIntent(this)` is not static and therefore it does not matter if you create the intent in `A` or in `B`.

This in A

```
startActivity(B.newIntent(this));
```

is no different than this in A

```
startActivity(newIntent(this));

private Intent newIntent(Context context) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, B.class);
   return intent;
}
```

> So I want to know what is better selection to calling new Activity?

In functionality it makes no difference. If there is any difference in memory usage, it will be so little you won't notice it.

As far as coding style goes, it would be better to keep the creation of the intent it in `A`, because `A` is starting `B`, and `B` should not care how `A` takes care of it.

Comment: As per you said "If there is any difference in memory usage, it will be so little you won't notice it." I have noticed it contains more than 15 MB heap size is it convenient and also face a issue of increasing heap size on every new activity calling with static method.

Comment: @JayeshKhasatiya The 15 MB heap is not "equal" on the different devices. If all your code has is `startActivity(B.newIntent(this));` this is more likely to be a memory leak, the `this` is not GC-able, and is making the memory hold the refference, until the "B intent" is used and destroyed. Heaps should always have some (7 MB+) allocated memmory, since the Linux (under Android) may use it for pagination. To answer, `So I want to know what is better selection to calling new Activity?` None. Both depend on the device, and the data that is behind it. I preffer `startActivity(B.newIntent(this));`

Comment: Adding a static method to a class does not increase anything by 15 MB, what exactly are you measuring?

Comment: 15 MB just an example and I know its varying device to device. But I have seen many application use first (static calling) method structure. why all guys prefer this kind structure? And Why we do not follow this kind of structure?

Comment: @JayeshKhasatiya structuring code is heavily reliant on personal preference. It's up to ourselves to decide how we want to do it. As for functionality, there is no difference.

Comment: @TimCastelijns:  Defining the same method "newIntent(Context context)" in each activity ... Is it a good code standard ? if that can be achieved with out this too by defining a single method in baseActivity. Even without using static too !!

Comment: Defining the same code in every activity is not a good standard. Repeated code should be refactored to for instance a BaseActivity class, yes. But we should not go into code style preferences here

Comment: " B should not care how A takes care of it" I disagree. I think "A should not care how B is created" makes more sense. Well the point of having the static intent method in B is so that you can put the intent extras in B and don't have to care about the correct keys in A.

Comment: @miva2 depends on how you look at it. `A` creates `B` so in a sense it must care how it is created. I'm not saying I don't agree with you, but there are different perspectives

Comment: True, it all depends on your usecase. I was not thinking "`A` creates `B`" but I was thinking "`A` wants to do something `B` knows how to do"